# postgres default list partition with many partitions

Tags: postgresql

I am planning to reduce the number of LIST partitions on several tables by removing the physical partitions for partition keys that have no or few entries and use a default partition instead.

For example, on one table, reduce the number of partitions from 8000 to 1000 plus default partition.

Another example would be to reduce the number of partitions from 6000 to 4000 plus default partition.

But I just realized that having n partitions next to a default partition, leads to a partition constraint on the default partition that has n entries. See sample below.

**Question: What would you consider to be the safe/sane/sound upper limit for the number of partitions a table can have next to a default partition as the `ANY (ARRAY[988, 989, 990, ...]` gets longer and longer?**

```
CREATE TABLE tst_t (
    c1 int4 NOT NULL,
    c2 int8 NOT NULL,
    c3 int8 NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST (c1);

CREATE TABLE tst_t_988 PARTITION OF tst_t  FOR VALUES IN (988);
CREATE TABLE tst_t_989 PARTITION OF tst_t  FOR VALUES IN (989);
CREATE TABLE tst_t_990 PARTITION OF tst_t  FOR VALUES IN (990);
CREATE TABLE tst_t_default PARTITION OF tst_t DEFAULT;

\d+ tst_t_default
                                      Table "public.tst_t_default"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 c1     | integer |           | not null |         | plain   |             |              |
 c2     | bigint  |           | not null |         | plain   |             |              |
 c3     | bigint  |           | not null |         | plain   |             |              |
Partition of: tst_t DEFAULT
Partition constraint: (NOT ((c1 IS NOT NULL) AND (c1 = ANY (ARRAY[988, 989, 990]))))
Access method: heap
```

Comment: Consider using `PARTITION BY RANGE` instead of `PARTITION BY LIST`?

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your suggestion, but RANGE partitioning makes the partition constraint of the default partition even messier it seems: `Partition constraint: (NOT ((c1 IS NOT NULL) AND (((c1 >= 988) AND (c1 < 989)) OR ((c1 >= 989) AND (c1 < 990)) OR ((c1 >= 990) AND (c1 < 991)) OR ((c1 >= 991) AND (c1 < 992)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition constraint is just like a check constraint, and it is no problem to have a large number of numbers in that. If anything, it will slow down inserting into the default partition a little bit. It should be easy to create a test setup any measure the overhead.

There is another problems with a default partition, however: you won't be able to add a new partition to the partitioned table if the default partition already contains a row that would belong into the new partition. You'd first have to delete such rows from the default partition.